# Is it possible to exclude the test parameters from being included in the NUnit 3 test result XML?

Tags: nunit

We use NUnit 3 to run deployment smoke tests with parameters read from VCS. It works like this:

1. Powershell reads the parameters from VCS and compose NUnit 3 console command line.
2. NUnit3 console runs the tests.

Some parameters are passwords.

The problem is that the end test result XML lists all the test parameters, including the passwords.

Is it possible to instruct NUni3 somehow to avoid including the test parameters in the test result XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature like that because the assumption is you would not pass in anything that needs to be secure.

Why is that? Imagine there were an argument like `--secret:password=XXX` which worked like a parameter but was not displayed in the results. In that case, your password would still be in clear in your script, for anyone to read. Also, it would be available to any test, which could do what it wanted with it, like write it somewhere.

A better approach is to use some sort of encryption, so that you are only passing in a key, which is not usable except by an account or program that knows how to decrypt it. There are various approaches to doing this,depending on how you are running tests. I believe you will find that VCS has a way of encrypting passwords that you may be able to use.

In any case, without such a "secret" option, the only way you could avoid publishing the password would be to create your own output format by writing an engine result writer extension. Your extension code would receive the entire nunit 3 output document and you could modify it to remove the passwords before saving the file.

Comment: The parameters are read from git version control using REST API with the credential of the account running the tests. Those who are not authorised to read the parameters, cannot run the tests. BUT, the test results are published openly, because they are troubleshooted by developers, not by the people who manage the parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "secret" parameter you can use. I edited my answer to give you a workaround, but it's fairly complicated.